# Django query extended USER table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a profile table which have a foreign key of the user.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I also have a COMMENT table which have a foreign key of the user.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to query the table COMMENT and also I want to get the image of the user which is in the PROFILE table. How can I query this in most effective way in django?.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Django = <1.4 the following is best practice:

```
 comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=1)
 comment.user.get_profile().image
```

Following the deprecation of native `Profile` model support (Django 1.5+) the following is still possible:

```
 comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=1)
 comment.user.profile.image
```

Django 1.5+ introduces custom auth models so you can do the following:

```
comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=1)
comment.user.image
```

At very least you should change your `ForeignKey` to a `OneToOne` relation for the user column on `Profile`, as Django =< 1.4 expects only one `User Profile` to be associated with a `User`.

References:

Django 1.4 `get_profile`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile

Django 1.5+ extending the user model:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: Nice.. Thanks for this info. This is very helpful. I just change the ForeignKey field to OneToOne

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with changing ForeignKey to OneToOneField on Profile model then you can do it like,

```
Comment.objects.all().select_related('user__profile')
```

The above one selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.

Otherwise you can get it this way

```
for comment in Comment.objects.all():
   print comment.user.profile_set.all()[0].image
```

Comment: I just change the ForeignKey to OneToOne field and works ok!.. Thanks for the reply. :D